# Where is Microsoft.ServiceBus.Notifications.NotificationHubClient?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, notifications, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I have started learning about notification hubs and have gone through some tutorials.

Now I need to send messages from my ASP.NET WebAPI 2 backend to the notification hub. So I decided to learn about the Notification Hubs Rest API.

On this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530746.aspx) It is written that Microsoft already provides a .NET wrapper around the REST API in the Microsoft.ServiceBus.Notifications.NotificationHubClient on this page.

But on clicking the link it says topic is no longer available.

Now I need to learn about how to send push notifications from my asp.net web api backend and azure website seems to have only one tutorial which is [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-windows-dotnet-notify-users/)

So can someone please point out where is Microsoft.ServiceBus.Notifications.NotificationHubClient or some tutorials or other library if this one is outdated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is there a specific reason you want to implement the solution using REST API directly? I would not recommend that unless you have the reason. There is a Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs library that you can use for your Web API solution, and the tutorial you mentioned is the right one (you can install it using NuGet). For more fast proof of concept implementation, you can skip the authentication part here, however it is good one to know.

Comment: Yes you can - that is why i am asking you why you want to go to rest api :) Install Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs in your Web Api project, import using Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs; in your controller, use CreateClientFromConnectionString(...), and you should be good to go with Send methods.

Comment: can you point out some more tutorials that use this Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs and also tutorials that teach how to create a notification in xml or json whatever?

Comment: I use rest api if i see that the standard libraries does not support something. For example, if i see that i need method to return N records instead of M records that can be returned with the standard method in the library.

Comment: Does the tutorial you mentioned (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-windows-dotnet-notify-users/) not work for you? Recently, i did that and it worked for me for Web Api sending the notificatins

Comment: It has the examples of json notifications payloads - var notif = "{ \"data\" : {\"message\":\"" + "From " + user + ": " + message + "\"}}";. Just change it into what you want.

Comment: last question is this outdated Microsoft.ServiceBus.Notifications.NotificationHubClient

Comment: Hi, I'm with the Notification Hubs engineering team. Sorry about the documentation confusion! Here is the library for notificationhubclient: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.notificationhubclient.aspx. I'll make sure we get that link fixed.

Best,
Mimi

Comment: but this is a different namespace?